# Export Data Pump all data from few schemas except one table structure only?

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

we use to make a copy of schemas from one database and move it to another for testing using this par file ...

```
DIRECTORY=EXPORT
DUMPFILE=QQS_PROD.DMP
LOGFILE=QQS_PROD.LOG
SCHEMAS=QQSDATA_PROD,QQSREPOSITORY_PROD,QQS_CENTRAL_PROD,QQS_BD_PROD,QQS_QD_PROD
FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP
EXCLUDE=TABLE:"IN ('SYS_HISTORY')"
```

then create the CONFIG_HISTORY with a script on the target database!

is there any way to NOT **EXCLUDE=TABLE:"IN ('SYS_HISTORY')"** and export the structure only of this table?

can I use something like this:

```
INCLUDE=TABLE:"IN ('SYS_HISTORY')"
QUERY=SYS_HISTORY:"where CON_ID < 0"
```

note: there is no CON_ID with value less than 0, it will return nothing when **CON_ID < 0**!

Comment: CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY ?

Comment: this will export METADATA_ONLY or The Structure only of the whole schemas, i need everything but only the structure of this table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can try something like,

```
DIRECTORY=EXPORT
DUMPFILE=QQS_PROD.DMP
LOGFILE=QQS_PROD.LOG
SCHEMAS=QQSDATA_PROD,QQSREPOSITORY_PROD,QQS_CENTRAL_PROD,QQS_BD_PROD,QQS_QD_PROD
FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP
query=SYS_HISTORY:"where 1=2"
```

This way, the metadata about table SYS_HISTORY will be copied but no data.
Note: since you are not prefixing table name (to exclude data from), with schema name, this filter will apply to this table in each schema specified.