# Selective data extract at Schema level

Tags: oracle, datapump

I am attempting to achieve the following within a single data pump export:

- *SCHEMA1* = Structures only
- *SCHEMA2* = Structures only
- *SCHEMA3* = Structures and data

The answer in this question only works on the table level:

- [Export Data Pump all data from few schemas except one table structure only?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51579/export-data-pump-all-data-from-few-schemas-except-one-table-structure-only)

It suggests removing data from a specific table using a filter:

```
SCHEMA2.table1: WHERE 1=2
```

I need the same but applied to all data in the schemas other than *SCHEMA3*.

How can this be done?

Comment: You should use a parameter file, then use simple SQL to generate QUERY clauses. something like `select 'query=' || owner || '.' || table_name || ':"where 1=2"' from dba_tables where owner in ('SCHEMA1','SCHEMA2');`. then specify `schemas=schema1,schema2,schema3` , that should mostly do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering options in Data Pump are still something that should be improved. Anyway, you could try the below parameters:

```
directory=data_pump_dir
dumpfile=dump.dmp
logfile=export.log
schemas=schema1,schema2,schema3
exclude=TABLE_DATA:" IN (select table_name from dba_tables where owner in ('SCHEMA1', 'SCHEMA2') union select partition_name from dba_tab_partitions where table_owner in ('SCHEMA1', 'SCHEMA2'))"
```

This excludes `TABLE_DATA` for all tables and partitions whose **name match the result of the query provided** in the `exclude` part.

And that is why this may not be appropriate for you. If you have a table called `T1` both in `SCHEMA1` and `SCHEMA3`, the data of `SCHEMA3.T1` will be excluded, because the above query returns `T1` from `SCHEMA1`, and Data Pump will ignore `TABLE_DATA` of all table called `T1`. If you have a partitioned table in `SCHEMA2`, with a partition called `P1`, the data of the table `SCHEMA3.P1` will be excluded. The above may work if your table and partition names are distinct accross all referenced schemas.

Or you could dynamically generate the expdp command or use DBMS_DATAPUMP to filter out all the table data from `SCHEMA3`.

But I would rather just run 2 seperate exports for `SCHEMA1,SCHEMA2` with `CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY` and a default export (`CONTENT=ALL`) for `SCHEMA3`.